# Angular routing module

Tags: angular, routes

I have following code in header component html

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
    <span> <img   src="/assets/images/logo.png" height=30 width=41></span>
    <a md-button routerLink="/home"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> 
    Home</a>
    <a md-button><span class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About</a>
    <a md-button routerLink="/menu"><span class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span> 
    Menu</a>
    <a md-button><span class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg"></span> Contact</a>

</md-toolbar>
```

and

Routing Module as

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'menu',  component: MenuComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

when I click the Menu icon on the header; following error appears on the console.
I am kind of clueless.

```
_this._renderer.removeClass is not a function
    at eval (common.js:2241)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ClassDirective.NgClass._toggleClass (common.js:2236)
    at eval (common.js:2215)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ClassDirective.NgClass._removeClasses (common.js:2215)
    at ClassDirective.set [as klass] (common.js:2079)
    at ClassDirective.set [as classBase] (class.js:126)
    at updateProp (core.js:12661)
    at c
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full code it's hard to know for sure. But here's one common gotcha that I've fallen into before with the Router Module. No guarantees that this will solve your problem, but it's definitely something to look at and could help other people stuck with similar errors.

Make sure you're calling `RouterModule.forRoot()` and passing in your `routes` object in your `app.module.ts` file. Otherwise you could get a lot of weird errors that will be really difficult to debug.

See the example from [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(
    appRoutes,
    { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
  )
  // other imports here
],
```

Comment: Why are you trying to export your routes object? You should just be able to define it in your app.module.ts file.

Comment: so i dont need this exports in NgModuls?

Comment: Try removing the `export`.

Comment: When I remove the export, nothing shows up on the screen.

Comment: Could you post your entire `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: It'son the answer 2

Comment: You should define your routes here. Then add the code that I posted above in the `imports` section under `@NgModule`

Comment: still doesn't work.  See the error message on Answer 3.  thank you

Comment: Turns out it's actually an entirely different problem. A quick google search was able to pick up the issue on github. I'll keep this answer up it case it helps anyone, but you probably want to take a look at my new answer below.

Comment: Also, could you please remove the 2 answers you posted with your code. I know you're new to this site but just for future reference, that's not the proper use of answers. It mucks up the answer section, making it really difficult for people who come across this question to find the solution. In the future, if somebody asks you to post more code, include it in your original question.

Comment: When the engine parses the html, what component is responsible for correctness of the syntax or semantics.?  Thank you

Comment: I'd be glad to help you, but that's out of the scope of your original question. I'd recommend looking at the angular docs and if necessary, asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
HeaderComponent.html:3 ERROR TypeError: _this._renderer.removeClass is not a function
    at eval (common.js:2241)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ClassDirective.NgClass._toggleClass (common.js:2236)
    at eval (common.js:2215)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ClassDirective.NgClass._removeClasses (common.js:2215)
    at ClassDirective.set [as klass] (common.js:2079)
    at ClassDirective.set [as classBase] (class.js:126)
    at updateProp (core.js:12661)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12368)
View_HeaderComponent_0 @ HeaderComponent.html:3
proxyClass @ compiler.js:14659
DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:15038
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1510
(anonymous) @ core.js:5925
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4708
ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:5925
(anonymous) @ core.js:5751
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4760
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
NgZone.run @ core.js:4577
next @ core.js:5751
schedulerFn @ core.js:4342
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:243
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:190
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:131
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:95
Subject.next @ Subject.js:56
EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4322
checkStable @ core.js:4725
onHasTask @ core.js:4773
ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:500
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
HeaderComponent.html:3 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 11, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported issue related to Flex-Layout interfering with the Router Module. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18922

Try making sure all of your dependencies are up to date. If that doesn't work, you may need to downgrade to an earlier version of angular.